# How to do the post hoc test in the linear mixed model if I have three predictors (two factor variables and one numeric variable)

Tags: r, mixed-models, linguistics

I'm using a linear mixed effects model to analyze the reaction time of learners of English as a second language. I have two factor variables - grammaticality (grammatical v.s. ungrammatical) and Finiteness (finite v.s. nonfinite); as well as one numeric variable - the proficiency score.

I'd like to analyze how their proficiency may affect their sensitivity to grammaticality and finiteness, so I built the model like this:

```r
fitnonnative7 <- lmer(data = nonnative,
                      formula = RT ~ Grammaticality * Finiteness * Proficiency + (Grammaticality|subject) + (Grammaticality|item))
```

I got a significant interaction in grammaticality:finiteness:proficiency; otherwise, no other main effects or interactions were found. However, what am I supposed to do next? Which functions/code may help to understand what is happening inside these three variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `marginaleffects` package to estimate contrasts. (Disclaimer: I am the author.) See the contrasts vignette for a lot of details:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/contrasts.html

In this example, `am` and `vs` are binary, and `wt` is numeric/continuous. First, we use the `comparisons()` function to see what happens to the predicted outcome when `vs` or `am` move from 0 to 1, for different values of the `wt` variable (using the `fivenum` function to set the variable at Tukey’s five numbers). Then, we plot the value of the contrasts in `am` and `vs` for different values of `wt` using the `plot_cco()` function:

```r
library(lme4)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lmer(mpg ~ am * vs * wt + (am | gear) + (vs | gear), data = mtcars)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = c("am", "vs"),
    interaction = FALSE,
    newdata = datagrid(wt = fivenum))
#>    rowid     type term contrast comparison std.error  statistic    p.value    conf.low conf.high predicted_lo predicted_hi      am     vs gear     wt
#> 1      1 response   am    1 - 0   7.353206  3.291220  2.2341883 0.02547069   0.9025326 13.803879    23.743324  31.09652941 0.40625 0.4375    3 1.5130
#> 2      2 response   am    1 - 0   2.266254  1.678246  1.3503705 0.17689718  -1.0230479  5.555555    20.649991  22.91624453 0.40625 0.4375    3 2.5425
#> 3      3 response   am    1 - 0  -1.600225  1.765295 -0.9064916 0.36467572  -5.0601390  1.859689    18.298817  16.69859236 0.40625 0.4375    3 3.3250
#> 4      4 response   am    1 - 0  -3.206111  2.205327 -1.4538031 0.14600091  -7.5284712  1.116250    17.322291  14.11618091 0.40625 0.4375    3 3.6500
#> 5      5 response   am    1 - 0 -11.971776  5.584590 -2.1437160 0.03205565 -22.9173722 -1.026180    11.991963   0.02018736 0.40625 0.4375    3 5.4240
#> 6      1 response   vs    1 - 0   3.845119  3.632085  1.0586531 0.28975778  -3.2736381 10.963875    25.048324  28.89344284 0.40625 0.4375    3 1.5130
#> 7      2 response   vs    1 - 0   2.999110  1.827767  1.6408606 0.10082636  -0.5832466  6.581467    20.258546  23.25765591 0.40625 0.4375    3 2.5425
#> 8      3 response   vs    1 - 0   2.356078  1.771024  1.3303481 0.18340360  -1.1150648  5.827221    16.617942  18.97401990 0.40625 0.4375    3 3.3250
#> 9      4 response   vs    1 - 0   2.089004  2.213747  0.9436510 0.34534803  -2.2498596  6.427868    15.105870  17.19487395 0.40625 0.4375    3 3.6500
#> 10     5 response   vs    1 - 0   0.631191  5.801561  0.1087968 0.91336370 -10.7396589 12.002041     6.852283   7.48347423 0.40625 0.4375    3 5.4240

plot_cco(mod, effect = "am", condition = "wt")
```

[image]

```r
plot_cco(mod, effect = "vs", condition = "wt")
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Vincent! Thank you so much for your wonderful R package!! I have some questions about the p-value in the result: I've got a significant main effect of Finiteness at Level 5 of proficiency (p=0.048). So it means that only at this level of proficiency, the reaction time between the two levels of Finiteness is significantly different right? I've also got very beautiful plots with the codes:) But the plot can only show us the trend across different levels of proficiency and it doesn't mean that at each level the contrast is significantly different - did I understand correctly? Thank you!